# Web API Curl post not found anything matching the request URI

Tags: asp.net, linux, curl, asp.net-web-api, flume-ng

I have a web API asp application in which I have a controller called SourceFlumeController there is a method post called `obtenerValores` that receives an int variable and returns a set of data when I use postman to post it works ok.

[image]

```
[
    {
        "ano": 2017,
        "mes": 1,
        "valor": 724242629.852258440265745
    },
    {
        "ano": 2017,
        "mes": 2,
        "valor": 588173802.519942843885072
    },
    {
        "ano": 2017,
        "mes": 3,
        "valor": 84633390.992432594067902
    }
]
```

The problem occurs when I try to post from a Linux virtual machine with curl this is my attempt

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8' -d '["body":{"ano":"2010"}'] http://xxx.xxx.xx.xxx/CSharpFlume/api/SourceFlume/obtenerValores
```

curl returns not found anything matching the request URI

So I tried with a GET method and it works

```
curl http://192.168.45.201/CSharpFlume/api/SourceFlume/getValores?ano=2017
```

My question is, what I am missing in curl Post method?

Comment: It's hard to tell without knowing what your server-side API looks like/accepts. But assuming it handles JSON body in POST requests properly, try changing your `curl` line `-d` argument to `'{"body":{"ano":"2010"}}'`.

Comment: Also, you can try experimenting with `curl` options on services like `http://httpbin.org`. For example, your Postman example above uses `x-www-form-urlencoded` (not JSON!) body. Test it how it looks on server-side with `curl -X POST -d ano=2010 http://httpbin.org/post`.

Comment: I have tried with `'{"body":{"ano":"2010"}}'` but i get the same error, sorry how should I use `http://httpbin.org/post` ?

Comment: Try with the line from my previous comment. Both on your endpoint and on httpbin..

Comment: `{
  "args": {}, 
  "data": "", 
  "files": {}, 
  "form": {
    "ano": "2010"
  }, 
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "*/*", 
    "Connection": "close", 
    "Content-Length": "8", 
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", 
    "Host": "httpbin.org", 
    "User-Agent": "curl/7.19.7 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7 NSS/3.13.1.0 zlib/1.2.3 libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.2.2"
  }, 
  "json": null, 
  "origin": "190.0.42.46", 
  "url": "http://httpbin.org/post"
}`
I get that on my VM, the web api is running on a IIS server

Comment: Have you tried running `curl -X POST -d ano=2010 ...` on your server endpoint?

Comment: Yes I have tried this `curl -d ano=2010 -X POST http://XxX.XxX.Xx.Xxx/CSharpFlume/api/SourceFlume/obtenerValores` and `"ano=2010"`

Comment: @randomir I found my error! my post method was receiving an int as parameter, but the right way is to receive an object, ty for your help!

Comment: Great, I'm glad to hear that! Sorry I couldn't have been of much help; it would have been easier if you had included some/more details about your server side (like a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)).